# #Backbone js . Adding a model to collection based on a test case ,It is throwing error as unable to set values for undefined

Tags: backbone.js

Unable to pass the Below tests case which is asking to add a element to the collection .
When i do taskCollection.add(), It is throwing error as unable to set values for undefined
Can anyone please check on how to pass this test case . I tried creating a new view and then do a addAll but it just does not work .. How to add a model to the collection . Test case is at the bottom

This is my JS Code

```js
//Define a global var task_id as 0
//Define your Model, Task Model

var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    task_id: 0,
    task_name: "abc",
    task_desc: "xyz",
  },
});
//Define your Collection, TasksCollection with Model as Task
var TasksCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Task,
});
var taskCollection = new TasksCollection();

//Define your View, TaskRecordsView with events buttons add(addTask),delete(deleteTask) and clear(clearInput)

var TaskRecordsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#todoapp",
  render: function () {},

  events: {
    "click #btnadd": "add",
    "click #btnclear": "remove",
  },
  initialize: function () {
    this.render();
  },
  addTask: function () {
    taskCollection.add([this.Task]); this.render();
  },
  clearInput: function () {
    this.render();
  },
  deleteTask: function () {
    this.render();
  },
});

var tasksView = new TaskRecordsView({
  collection: taskCollection,
});

taskCollection.on("add", function () {
  tasksView.render();
});
taskCollection.on("remove", function () {
  tasksView.render();
});
```

HTML Code:

```html
<!-- Hmtl -->
<html>    
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">   
</head>    
<body>    
<div id="todoapp">
      <table style="width:75%;" id="tblinput">
         <thead>
            <h1>My Todos</h3>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>Task Name:</td>
               <td> 
                  <input type="text" id="task_name" placeholder="Enter the task name" /> 
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Description:</td>
               <td> 
                  <textarea  id="task_desc" placeholder="Enter the Task Description"></textarea> 
               </td>
            </tr>
            <td> 
            </td>
            <td> 
               <button id="btnadd">Add</button> 
               <button id="btnclear">Clear</button> 
            </td>
            </tr> 
      </table>
      <div id="dvcontainer"></div>
    </div>

<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="lib/backbone/backbone.js"></script>  
<script  type = "text/javascript"  src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

**BELOW IS THE TEST CASE I AM TRYING TO PASS**

```js
        describe('Event testing application', function() {
            var task,taskCollection,view;
            beforeEach(function() {
            document.body.innerHTML='<div id="dummy_body"><input type="text" id="task_name" placeholder="Enter the task name" /><textarea  id="task_desc" placeholder="Enter the Task Description"></textarea><button id="btnadd">Add</button><button id="btnclear">Clear</button>  <div id="dvcontainer"></div> </div>';
                task = new Task({
                    taskid:0,
                    taskName: "ssa", 
                    taskDesc: "sdsa",
                    });
            taskCollection=new TasksCollection({model: Task });
                view=new TaskRecordsView();
        
              });
        
              afterEach(function() {
                document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('dummy_body'));
              });
        describe('Testing sample app', function() {
        it("TaskCollection length after adding one task", function () {
          $("#task_name").val("Meeting");
          $("#task_desc").text("At 4 pm");
          view.addTask();
          expect(view.addTask()).toBe(1);
        });
        it('TaskCollection length after adding two task', function() {
           $('#task_name').val('task1');
           $('#task_desc').text('desc1');
            if(view.addTask()==1){
                $('#task_name').val('task2');
                $('#task_desc').text('desc2');
                view.addTask();
            }   
                expect(view.addTask()).toBe(2);
                });
           });
    });
```

**ERROR i am getting is :-**
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Event testing application Testing sample app
TaskCollection length after adding one task FAILED
Expected undefined to be 1.
at UserContext. (test/index_test.js:27:33)
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 1 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.038 secs)  [1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Event testing application Testing sample app
TaskCollection length after adding two task FAILED
Expected undefined to be 2.
at UserContext. (test/index_test.js:49:33)
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 2 of 2 (2 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.041 secs)

Comment: All your methods is just doing `render` , it's not adding to collection anywhere...

Comment: When i tried this ,

`addTask: function () {
    taskCollection.add([this.Task]);
    this.task_id = this.task_id + 1;
    this.render();
  }`

Then also an error  **bold** TaskCollection length after adding one task FAILED

 Expected undefined to be 1.

     at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:45:33)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the actual code that you're trying to execute and the error you're getting for that particular piece of code. It's hard to read code blocks in comments...

Comment: Updated the code,  testcase code , and the error i am getting .. See if this helps please.

Comment: `taskCollection.add([this.Task]); this.render();` in this line, `this.Task` is undefined. I don't see any code that is setting  a `Task` property on view instance...
Also this `addTask` method doesn't return a number so `expect(view.addTask()).toBe(2)` is going to fail.

Your code should be something like `addTask: function () {
    this.collection.add({// data}); 
  }`

And expectation would be collection length increase like `expect(view.collection.length).toBe(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your `addTask` is not doing what you expect. `this.Task` should be a instance of the model `Task` created by you at  some point of the code.

```
addTask: function () {
    
    taskCollection.add([this.Task]);
    this.render();
},
```

probably what you want is something like this:

```js
addTask: function () {
    let newTask = new Task({
        task_name: $("#task_name").val(),
        task_desc: $("#task_desc").text()
    });
    taskCollection.add(newTask);
    // this.render(); // no need to be called here as you have a listener for "add" events
},
```

Also your `addTask` does returns nothing `expect(view.addTask()).toBe(1);` so this check does not make sense. And expecting `addTask` to return the number of tasks does not make two much sense for me.

I will use something like:

```
// in TasksRecordView

numberOfTasks: function() {
    return taskCollection.length;
}
```

and change your tests to: `expect(view.numberOfTasks()).toBe(1);`

BTW you are using a custom `task_id` in your models, with my code it will always be `0` you should handled this issue or remove `task_id` and just use the internal [cid](https://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) of Backbone.

I case that the test case can not be changed as asked in one of the comments, just return the number of tasks from addTask. I don't see it as a good design but should work;

```js
addTask: function () {
    let newTask = new Task({
        task_name: $("#task_name").val(),
        task_desc: $("#task_desc").text()
    });
    taskCollection.add(newTask);
    // this.render(); // no need to be called here as you have a listener for "add" events
    return taskCollection.length;
},
```

Comment: Thanks much . This helped!

Comment: I’m also facing the same issue with same test cases. I do not have permission to modify the test case. What can be done to pass the above test cases?

Comment: @karthik it's hard to say without seeing your code. Probably you should create a new question for your issue.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga it is the same code discussed above. both the test case doesn't pass. Only either of the test case passes.

Comment: I edited my answer to review your case @karthik

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. But I already tried this. It works only when the test case expects to return 1. The next test case expects to return 2 - it fails.  Both the test cases needs to pass. @FranciscoPuga